# android database error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc, android-emulator

I have created android database by SQLiteBrowser program and then import it. When i run my code it gives an unexpected error. İ have made

1. I  open android sdk and avg meneger and lunch the emulator.
2. Then I import my database into /data/data/mypackage path.

   As I read, I have to import it /data/data/mypackage/databases. But when I open the path mypackage, I can see only lib folder. So I added into /data/data/mypackage.
3. my code part is

   ```
   private static String dbName = "mobileGuideDatabase.db";                
   private static String dbPath = "/data/data/de.Guide" + dbName;

   SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

   try {
     checkDB = db.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
   } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
     throw ex;
   }
   ```

So what is wrong with this section?

Answer (score 2):

Your db path seems to be missing a slash. It will now be:
"/data/data/de.GuidemobileGuideDatabase.db", but I assume you want it to be "/data/data/de.Guide/mobileGuideDatabase.db"

Comment: i have corrected to missing slash but i take same error still

Comment: What is the exception? Which line?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you running on the Phone directly, The Phone will n't allow to access the data folders.

1. Create our own Folder
2. copy the db into the location
3. Open the DB from that location

For the reference

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {   
         String path=mContext.getDir("Folder_Name",
          Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).getAbsolutePath(); 
          DB_PATH=path;  
          boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();   

          if(!mDataBaseExist)   {     
          try       {       copyDataBase();      }       
          catch (IOException mIOException)       
        {      Log.d("Exception",mIOException.getMessage());    
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");      
        } 
      }  
   }  

   private boolean checkDataBase()  {      
     Log.d(TAG, "In checkDataBase :::::"); 
     File dbFile = new File( DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME);      
     Log.d("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());     
     return dbFile.exists();  }   

    //Copy the database from assets  
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException  {      
      Log.d(TAG, "In copyDataBase :::::");      
      InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);     
      String outFileName = DB_PATH  + DATABASE_NAME;      
      Log.d(TAG, "In copyDataBase  outFileName:::::"+outFileName);      
      OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);      
      byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];      int mLength;      

      while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)      {         
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);      
      }     

        mOutput.flush();      
       mOutput.close();     
       mInput.close();  
   }   

     //Open the database, so we can query it  
   public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException  {      
    //DB_PATH +     String mPath = DB_PATH+ DATABASE_NAME;      
     Log.v("mPath", mPath);      
     mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 
     SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);      
      return mDataBase != null;  
   }
```